# Microsoft Graph User.Read

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing an .Net Core application with Angular Frontend.

Now users are authenticated with Azure Active Directory, which is configured over the Azure Portal.
The users are succesfully authenticated, but as a developer, I still do not now, which user has authenticated.

There are lots of exmaples how to retrieve the information about the user, which is done with
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me. But when I call this, I am getting an 401 Unauthorized response. So there must be a way to get a Token or something like that.

I am having an client-ID, tenant-ID as well as an AppServiceAuthSession Cookie. Can anyone provide an code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an secret to the application and then call `https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can go to [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) find your app and then locate "config" --> "authsettings". Edit the `additionalLoginParams` in json as:

```
"additionalLoginParams": [
  "response_type=code id_token",
  "resource=<the client id of your app in azure ad>"
],
```

Apart from this, you also need to edit the redirect uri of your app like:

```
https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

After that, you can get the access token by request `https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`. You can use the access token to request graph api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. By the way, maybe there are some information in the response of `https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`. If the information is enough, you do not need to use access token request the graph api.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting  `401 Unauthorized response` as you don't have right token to access the API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. The right approach is to use MSAL libraries to get token for your application(by authenticating) and use it for API.

Please find step-by-step tutorial using **.Net core** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core) and code sample [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-dotnet-core).

Please find step-by-step tutorial using **Angular** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular) and code sample [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-angularspa).